# How can I display extended Unicode character in a C# console?

Tags: c#, unicode, astral-plane

I'm trying to display a set of playing cards, which have Unicode values in the 1F0A0 to 1F0DF range. Whenever I try to use chars with more than 4 chars in their code, I get errors. Is it possible to use these characters in this context? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

char AceOfSpades = '\u1F0A0'; immediately upon typing gives me the error "Too many characters in character literal" This still shows up with either of the Unicode or UTF8 encodings. If I try to display '\u1F0A' like above... With Unicode it shows '?' With UTF8 it shows 3 characters.

I tried all the given options for OutputEncoding `string AceOfSpades = "\U0001F0A0";`
Default, Unicode, ASCII:  `??`
UTF7: `+2DzcoA-`
UTF8: four wierd characters
UTF32 , BigEndianUnicode: IOException
`Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32;`, despite being an option, crashes even if it's the only line of code.
UTF16 was not on the list.

How can I check which version of Unicode I'm using?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get errors"? Do you mean compile-time errors, or it just doesn't display properly? Is this on the command line console?

Comment: Also, please provide a simple code sample that manifests the problem you're facing.

Comment: I thought the output was limited from \u0000 to \uFFFF, but I may be mixing things up now.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_UTF-16_encoding_procedure

Comment: You are not going to find a font that can be used for the console window that has these glyphs.

Comment: There are very few fonts that contain glyphs for these characters, probably only DejaVu Sans fonts (version 2.33 or newer), Symbola, and Quivira.

Comment: "UTF16 was not on the list." UTF-16 is called System.Text.Encoding.Unicode or System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode. Which terminal emulator/console host/whatever are you using? What OS?

Answer (score 5):

In order to use characters from outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, you need to escape them with `\U`, not `\u`. That requires eight hexadecimal digits (which, to be honest, makes little sense, since all Unicode characters can be written with six hexadecimal digits).

However, the type `char` in .NET can only represent UTF-16 code units, meaning that characters outside the BMP require a pair of `char`s (a surrogate pair). So you have to make it a string.

```
string AceOfSpades = "\U0001F0A0";
```

Comment: Check out the documentation of char: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.71).aspx
"The Char value type represents a Unicode character, also called a Unicode code point, and is implemented as a 16-bit number ranging in value from hexadecimal 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. A single Char cannot represent a Unicode character that is encoded as a surrogate pair. However, a String, which is a collection of Char objects, can represent a Unicode character encoded as a surrogate pair."

Comment: @Ciemnl What do you want me to check there? (FWIW http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx is the latest version of the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume (until you edit your post for clarity) that your symbols are not displaying properly. If this is not the case, I will delete this answer.

Set your console's encoding to Unicode or UTF-8.

`Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`

or

`Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`.

Make sure the font can display Unicode/UTF-8 characters (like Lucida Console).

Comment: `char AceOfSpades = '\u1F0A0';`
immediately upon typing gives me the error 
"Too many characters in character literal"

This still shows up with either of the Unicode or UTF8 encodings.
If I try to display '\u1F0A' like above...
With Unicode it shows '?'
With UTF8 it shows 3 characters.

Comment: @Nigel you have to write `string ace = "\U0001F0A0"` if you convert this to a char array you will notice that it has a length of 2 because the ace of spades character is on an extended plane in UTF-16 and so has to represented by two 16 bit `char`s called a 'surrogate pair'. Hence, you can't store the ace of spades character in a single `char` which can only take 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I am displaying 10 Egyptian hieroglyphs from the Extended Unicode in a Windows application (not console) like that:

```
string single_character = "\U00013000";//first ancient hieroglyph

//get the Unicode index
Encoding enc = new UTF32Encoding(false, true, true);
byte[] b = enc.GetBytes(single_character);
Int32 code = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   //convert from int Unicode index to display character
   string glyph = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(code); //single one

   textBox1.Text += glyph;

   code++;
 }
```

You also need a font that supports these.